# why there is no utf-8 encoding in firefox?

Tags: firefox, unicode, utf-8

Why there is no  utf-8 encoding in firefox?
Maybe it is wrong for firefox to write encoding unicode in the encoding   line,should  `utf-8` or `unicode`  encoding  be displayed in the encdoing line?
What is the reason?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what answer you're expecting here. Are you looking for people to agree or disagree that Firefox is labelling this wrong? Is there something going wrong which seems to be caused by this? And either way, it's off topic for this site because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This option is UTF-8, yes. It used to say “Unicode (UTF-8)” which was clearer.

It seems when the encoding menu was tidied ([bug 805374](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=805374) I think) the encoding labels were made ‘friendlier’ by replacing the technical encoding name with a more general description, or removing it when it's the only selectable option.

It makes sense that other UTF encodings are not included: as non-ASCII-compatible encodings they can't easily be mistaken and switched between; UTF-8 is the only Unicode-family encoding that fits here. But the result of calling UTF-8 just “Unicode” is unfortunate in that Microsoft have always (misleadingly) used the term “Unicode” to mean UTF-16LE.

Comment: Which is even worse than the way Microsoft have always called UTF-8 by the bizarre moniker “UTF-8 without BOM”, and a bombed UTF-8 just “UTF-8”. It’s all very Orwellian.

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning(*as per my understanding*) not to add it as utf-8 might be because it allows the user to set the utf encoding as per your need like utf-16 or utf-8 etc.

Firefox uses Unicode and to use it it uses `charset=utf-8`

You need to understand that Firefox will use the encoding specified in a meta tag if the server does not send encoding via the HTTP response headers.

Its specified like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: Downvoter kindly care to leave a comment, so that I can improve my answer. :)

Comment: Firefox defaults to latin1, unfortunately, and this cannot be fixed on the client, so if the server doesn’t specify a charset you’re FUBAR with Firefox.